# Unable to extract text from a link in imacros

Tags: javascript, regex, imacros

This is the HTML tags from where I'm extracting data

```
<div class="rLB">
<div class="propDBlock">
<div class="sepBlock" onclick="trackSearchResultDetails('1', '21', '26617371', 'V', '4442');detailViewTrack('26617371');">
<div class="proBrf">
<a data-id="26617371" class="property-sticky-link" href="/propertyDetails/1-BHK-330-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Kalyan-in-Thane&id=4d423236363137333731" target="_blank" onclick="stopPage=true;callDetailPropertData('26617371');addViewedPropertyToCookie('26617371',1);detailViewTrack('26617371');clicktrack('1', 'propertyId=26617371,'+'21', 'div'+',sessionId='+sessionId  ,'Sale','Kalyan','Agent','38','Thane' ,'9200','', 'N','11.2 Lac','','1','Multistorey Apartment','','','23','','',false,'','',''); trackPropertyPosition('1', '21', '26617371', 'div')">
<input type="hidden" id="bedroomVal26617371" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="propertyVal26617371" value="Apartment">
1 BHK Apartment
<span class="noWrapLocality">
for sale in
<span id="localityName26617371" class="localityFirst">Kalyan</span>
<span onclick="stopPage=true;" class="nearByTime"><span id='localitySecond26617371' class="localitySecond"></span>
</span>
</span>
<input type="hidden" id="propertyArea26617371" value="330 sqft">
<b class="areaValue">330&nbsp;sqft</b>
</a>
</div>
```

I'm using

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:property-sticky-link&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/propertyDetails/.(.+?)BHK:/);")
PROMPT "VAR1={{VAR1}}"
```

but  it gives me "multiple" text `"BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartment1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartment1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan690 sqft"`

I just want the text  **"1 BHK Apartment for sale in Kalyan"**

Any idea on how do I go about it. Thanks in advance

Comment: *...this just gives me multiple text* what is the output?

Comment: Instead of adding output in comments move it to question (edit) and apply formatting for clean reading.

Comment: @Asunez updated the post ,please check

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...  I was able to figure out the answer:

```
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:property-sticky-link EXTRACT=TXT
SET LinkText {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=B ATTR=CLASS:areaValue EXTRACT=TXT
SET areaValue {{!EXTRACT}}
SET FinalResult EVAL(" var x=\"{{LinkText}}\"; x=x.replace(\"{{areaValue}}\",\"\"); x=x.replace(/\\s/g,' '); x=x.replace(/ {1,}/g,\" \"); x; ")
PROMPT {{FinalResult}}
```

Basically, what we're doing is grabbing the link text as defined by the `property-sticky-link` class, then grabbing the square footage text via the `areaValue` class. Each has their own "variable" `LinkText` and `areaValue`.

We use the EVAL function to use javascript's replace method to remove the square footage text from the LinkText `x=x.replace(\"{{areaValue}}\",\"\");`, and then some regex to remove the whitespaces and replace them with a space via `x=x.replace(/\\s/g,' ');`.  Unfortunately, this caused some double spaces between some of the words, so I do another replace to find the double spaces and replace them with a single space with the following `x=x.replace(/ {1,}/g,\" \");`.

The final results become:
`1 BHK Apartment for sale in Kalyan`

You should be able to extract the information you seek using my solution as a template.

Comment: Did this help at all?